# How does the python-pptx get shape combinations?

Tags: python, office365, powerpoint, python-pptx

I tried to get the text content of each text box in the PPT, which was fine under normal circumstances, but I found that if two text boxes were combined into a combined shape, the text content in the combined shape could not be read.
Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: If two text boxes were combined, then the resulting shape won't be a textbox. I guess you can use `has_text_frame` to check if a shape has text frame or not before reading. Additionally, you could check if there are `shapes` inside a particular shape to determine if it is a grouped shape.

Comment: When two shapes (rectangle & ellipse) that each contain text are combined, the text in each shape is deleted; the new combined shape is a freeform, one that has a textrange with no text.  I suspect you're not seeing a combined shape but something else.  Can you post an example slide for us to look at?

Comment: In PowerPoint there is _mergeing_ two or more shapes and there is _grouping_ two or more shapes, there is no _combining_ shapes per se. A group shape has no text-frame and cannot itself contain text. You must access each of the shapes inside the group which can contain text.

Comment: @scanny Yes and thanks for the reminder re "merge" vs "combine". In the example I gave above, I should have said "merge". When you merge shapes, the resulting freeform has a textframe, but no text until you add it. The original shapes no longer exist, so any text they held is gone.

Comment: That's good to know about merging, thanks @SteveRindsberg :)

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg I can probably guess how it works, but I can't write the code

Comment: @mincla If it were possible to get the original text from merged shapes after they're merged, I could help you do it in VBA, but not python. However see the previous comments; it doesn't seem that there will be any text to GET.  Unless you mean that the shapes have been grouped rather than merged.